# Endpoint removing hash and everything after in string parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6.0 API project using Web API but having some trouble with getting a string value to pass through properly.

The endpoint is:

```
[HttpGet("contact/{userId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetUserAsync(string userId)
{
    var user = await _userService.GetUserAsync(userId);

    return user is null ? NotFound() : Ok(user);
}
```

When I pass in a `userId` with a `#` it strips off the hash and everything after. For example, if I pass in `example-id-#1` the endpoint recieves `example-id-`.

If I pass in a string without a `#` the whole string comes through.

So my questions are:

1. Why does Web API strip the value?
2. How would I fix this **without changing the value passed in?**

Thanks!

Comment: # is the where client-side params start. I am pretty sure that ASP.NET doesn't even receive the part after #. So, if you need hashtag in your query params, try to encode it before sending.

Comment: `#` is a [Fragment identifier](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-you-can-share-links-that-anchor-to-any-text-on-a-webpage/#:~:text=The%20URI%20fragment%20is%20the,you're%20reading%20right%20now!), like @cemahseri said encode if you meant to send as part of request

Comment: Don't use such IDs because they result in bad URLs. `#` is the delimiter for the [URI Fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment). Whatever created that URL should try to URL-encode the ID at least

Comment: `without changing the value passed in` what you passed in was `example-id-`. You *have* to change what you pass if you want the entire string to be treated as a single value. You'd have the same problem if you attempted to pass `?` as part of the ID too, as everything after it would be treated as a query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is  *reserved symbol* in Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) schema, which defines fragment of URI:

[image]

> Fragment: An optional fragment component preceded by a hash (#). The
> fragment contains a fragment identifier providing direction to a
> secondary resource, such as a section heading in an article identified
> by the remainder of the URI. When the primary resource is an HTML
> document, the fragment is often an id attribute of a specific element,
> and web browsers will scroll this element into view.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

So in your example if URI is `http://localhost:3000/contact/example-id-#1`. It means following:

- Schema - `http`
- Host - `localhost`
- Port - `3000`
- Path - `/contact/example-id-` with two segments, `contact` and `example-id-`
- Fragment - `1`

Attribute `[HttpGet("contact/{userId}")]` roughly means for asp.net binder:
"in the Path, take the next Segment after Segment `contact` and pass it
as input parameter named userId". As you can see from the definition of URI, it correctly takes value `example-id-`.

If client wants to pass something, which includes reserved URI character, it should pass it URL encoded way, which basically means reserved characters will be substituted with codes to not mess with URI schema. So the URI will look like `http://localhost:3000/contact/example-id-%231`.

> How would I fix this without changing the value passed in?

It would be not so easy. You can get URI, which were used to hit the action, with `UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(HttpRequest)` as a string, and then parse it manually to extract the needed part. But please don't do it. It breaks URI scheme expectations, and could bring problems in routing.

Comment: Whilst this doesn't *techically* answer the question I did wonder if this would be the case. I don't have control of the code calling this but will feedback that it must be changed. I would rather avoid any unpleasant hacks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out # is a Fragment Identifier.
You can encode the `string` value before sending it to your API and then decode it.

```
        var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("example#test");
        var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
```